# Create Azure database in resource group programmatically using C#

Tags: database, azure, azure-resource-group

I'm trying to create a Azure database using a master database as a template using C#. I have the database creation working but I cannot find a way to specify the resource group for the new database.

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet requires Windows Azure management class library.

If you have not installed it, run the below command in Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries -Pre
```

The code below shows how to get a subscription of cloud credentials using C#.

```
public static string subscriptionId = "{Your-Subscription-id}"; 

        public static string base64EncodedCertificate = "Your-certificate-Base64-string"; 

        static SubscriptionCloudCredentials getCredentials() 

        { 

            return new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedCertificate))); 

        }
```

The code below shows how to create a SQL database using C# code.

```
static void Main(string[] args) 

      { 

          

          SqlManagementClient client = new SqlManagementClient(getCredentials()); 

            //Server Name is your SQL Azure DataBase server name, for example:mysqlserver001 

          client.Databases.Create("{Server-Name}", new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql.Models.DatabaseCreateParameters() 

          { 

              Name = "SqlDBTest", 

              MaximumDatabaseSizeInGB = 1, 

              CollationName = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", 

              Edition="Web" 

          }); 

          

          Console.ReadLine(); 

      }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where I specify the Resource Group. I couldn't find any mention of Resource Group in DatabaseCreateParameters

Comment: Also I can't find any method down the function chain to set the Resource Group. I 'm currently using the Fluent version of this for creating Storage Accounts in Resource Groups.